# Why (null == false) and (null == true) both return false?

Tags: javascript, null, boolean

I know that `null` is an object with no attributes or functions.

However, I am confused that why `console.log(null == false);` and `console.log(null == true);` both return false.

What are the conversion rules between `null` and `boolean`?

Comment: They both equal false because null does not equal true or false. Just like `1` does not equal `"pizza"` or `{}`. When used alone in like if statements it gets coerced to boolean false because it is a falsey value

Comment: Null is a literal and false is boolean,may be both are uncomparable types

Comment: Check out the concepts of "truthy" and "falsey" in JavaScript. There's more happening behind the scenes of the `==` operator than initially meets the eye. You're running into one of the odd edge cases.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is because the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) requires that if [`Type(x)`](http://es5.github.io/#Type) or [`Type(y)`](http://es5.github.io/#Type) is a Boolean in the expression `x == y` then the Boolean value should be coerced to a number via [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3), which converts `true` to 1 and `false` to `+0`.

This means that any comparison of `true == something` or `something == true` results in `1 == something` or `something == 1` (replacing `true` and `1` with `false` and `+0` for `false`).

[The Null type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.2) does not compare as equal to either 1 or +0 (in fact, null is only comparable to `undefined` in the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)).

There is a detailed discussion of all of the different kinds of equality in JavaScript on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) that is well worth looking at if you want to know more.

However, if you coerce `null` to a number it is [coerced to `+0`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) so `+null == false` actually returns `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have another confusion, I know that `isNaN(null)` equals `false` and `Number(null)` equals `0`, why is null coercible to `undefined` not `0`

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are equivalent in this case most likely because they are the only two elements in JS which cannot handle any sort of property access. `(0).toString() === "0" but `(null).anything` results in a `TypeError`.

Comment: For a complete answer, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: @SeanVieira why are you writing false becomes +0 after ToNumber-Operation? is it not just like 0, futhermore I tried to execute ToNumber(false) in the Chrome-DevTools Console, though it was not defined, is it a deprecated Function?

Comment: `ToNumber` is [an operation described in the ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) not a function you can call (it is, in effect, the description of a routine the JS engine must have, not something the JS engine must expose to the language via a function).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the current discussion. `null >= false` returns `true`.

I believe that it is because this is interpreted as `!(null < false)`

Comment: it's more probably because "ToNumber" routine is called on both side before the comparaison is made, and "ToNumber" set both false and null to +0.

Answer (score 2):

The value `null` is a JavaScript literal represents an "empty" value or "undefined". `null` is one of JavaScript's primitive values. It is neither equal to boolean `true` nor equal to boolean `false` because it's value is undefined. The value of `null` is more inclined towards false even though it is not `false`. That's why it's called "falsey" operators and an `if (var) { }` block does not get executed when `var` is `null`.

Comment: `var` should not be used as a variable name, since it's a reserved word.  example should say `someVar` instead of `var`.

Comment: Do not confuse "..its value is undefined" with the value of `undefined`.  Better stated as "..its value is unknown".

Answer (score 2):

Answer : There no relative aspect between null and boolean.

MDN Source:-

> The value null is a literal (not a property of the global object like
>   undefined can be). In APIs, null is often retrieved in place where an
>   object can be expected but no object is relevant. When checking for
>   null or undefined beware of the differences between equality (==) and
>   identity (===) operators (type-conversion is performed with the
>   former).
>
> ```
> // foo does not exist, it is not defined and has never been initialized:
> > foo
> "ReferenceError: foo is not defined"
>
> // foo is known to exist now but it has no type or value:
> > var foo = null; foo
> "null"
> ```
>
> Difference between null and undefined
>
> ```
> typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)
> typeof undefined   // undefined
> null === undefined // false
> null  == undefined // true
> ```

[JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Comment: You should probably make it clearer which parts of this answer you took from the source and which parts you wrote yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing