# Second conditional with null value

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code:

```
function listToArray(list) {
    var array = [];
    for(var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
      console.log(node.rest);
      array.push(node.value);
    }

    return array;
}
```

E.g.: An array like `[1, 2, 3]` would look in list form like this `{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null }}}`.

The conditional of the for loop in the function will eventually result in `null`. My question is, how does this conditional work? Usually you'll have a boolean expression, e.g.: `i <= 10`. AFAIK, `null` doesn't evaluate to a falsey value... So how does the conditional work?

Comment: `null` *is* falsey in JavaScript

Comment: Falsy values in JS: `false`, `0`, empty string, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`.

Comment: Why does the title say **second** conditional? There's only one conditional in your code.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, edited it now; @alex, barmar; how come `'' == false` equals `true`, but `null == false` does not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632391/why-null-false-and-null-true-both-return-false

Comment: Being falsy is not the same thing as `== false`.

Comment: Yes, I see where my thinking has gone wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in for loop is an expression that is evaluated at each iteration.If it evaluates to true , statement is executed.Since null,0,etc. are counted as false, it doesnt executes.

Source :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Right. But you can't see that with `null == false` like you could with `'' == false`.

Comment: In conditions , null value is treated as false.Here in null==false , you are checking if null == false which is not , null and false are different things

Comment: So it has to do with context? In an equals it is not false, in a condition it is.

Comment: if(false) or if(null)  , same thing but null is not equal to false. the '==' operator try to convert operands to same type.Check 2=="2".Since null means no value , null==false returns false

Comment: I see where my thinking has gone wrong. Thanks you.