# Why is this NULL variable truthy?

Tags: javascript, browser

I've known `null` to be **`falsy`**. Then why does it act as if it is a **`truthy`**?

```js
var status = null;

console.log('status:', status);

if(!!status) {
  console.log('status is truthy');   // it should not print
}

if(!!null) {
  console.log('null is truthy');   // it should not print
}
```

Comment: What does !! do? Shouldn't it be !

Comment: @PascalClaes `!!` converts the value to boolean

Comment: you see `console.log(status)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632391/why-null-false-and-null-true-both-return-false answers your question.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, that's what's surprising to OP

Comment: `console.log(status)` gives `null` which is falsy

Comment: @noobie Without looking at documentation. When `!!` converts a value to boolean, how exactly does it do that? What "actions" are performed?

Comment: Use a different variable name. You are conflicting with [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) which has setters that make it a string.

Comment: @Federico What Nina means is that the `null` output comes from `console.log(status)`, not from `console.log('null')`. OP's code is misleading

Comment: @JeremyThille IMHO it's not. There's an order to those `console.log`s, so it's clear that `null` is printed by the first one and `status` is printed by the second one.

Comment: Exactly. That's precisely what Nina said.

Comment: @JeremyThille then I don't understand what her comment has to do with the question.

Comment: Because OP says `console.log('null') // it should not print`. And it _does not_ print. The `null` we see does not come from here. It comes from `log(status)`. So OP's mislead by his own code

Comment: @JeremyThille now I understand, but I didn't read it like this. I think OP *knows* that doesn't print and was just using it to prove that `!!status` should behave like `!!null` and was surprised it didn't. The problem, I think, is that they meant `//does not print` instead. But I'm not in their head, so I'll just let it die here :)

Comment: use const status = null, everything will be fine

Comment: or `let status = null`

Answer (score 8):

The issue is there is already a [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status), with which you conflict. It has setters that always make it a string, which causes your problems.

Comment: Dear god, I was going nuts why it is initialized as a string when given to variable and stays special value null when not.

Comment: Why status holds "null" as a string?

Comment: `window.name` behaves the same way

Comment: see `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "status")`, i am not sure what exactly it does (the setter is native code), but it converts to string, and `String(null) === "null"`

Answer (score 4):

Change variable name `status` to something else (like `status1`) and the problem vanishes. This happens due to conflict with [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) object property of windows.

```js
var status1 = null;


console.log('status1 -->', status1)

if(!!status1) {
  console.log('status')   // it should not print
}

if(!!null) {
  console.log('null')   // it should not print
}
```

NOTE: No matter what value you assign to `window.status` it'll get converted back to string. See this:

```js
console.log(typeof window.status)

window.status = 4;   // type Number

console.log(typeof window.status) // still it remains string
```

Comment: This is still misleading. The output is `null`, but we can't be sure if it comes from the 1st or the 3rd `console.log`. Change the first one to `console.log("status1 = ", status1)`

Comment: @JeremyThille edited the answer

Comment: It adds a working demonstration