# null >= false and null <= false both return true in javascript

Tags: javascript

what explains this in javascript?

```
null >= false
null <= false
```

both returned true. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is null in JavaScript bigger than -1, less than 1, but not equal (==) to 0? What is it exactly then?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407544/why-is-null-in-javascript-bigger-than-1-less-than-1-but-not-equal-to-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why (null == false) and (null == true) both return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632391/why-null-false-and-null-true-both-return-false)